# Please provide an example of creating a recurring event using new Lightning model

Tags: lightning, rest-api, calendar

Winter'19 release has made the new recurring event model available which is very different from the original model for series. Could someone please provide a REST API (v44) or APEX example of creating a new series?

And another question. The new model occurrences don't have RecurrenceActivityId anymore that used to link them to their master event.
Any guide out there on how to process the v44 series and manage the master event?

Thank you.